# Error: Cannot invoke setValue on a background thread in Android Java

Tags: java, android, android-threading

This issue does not include Livedata. I have read through several questions but have not found the answer to my issue the file below gives the error. simulatedUpdate() is called from a background Thread. The problem is with the call receivedLocationUpdate() method that is being called within simulatedUpdate(). I assume the parameters passed are calling the set... methods in some way. I need to know why this occurs and how I can call this method in the current situation.

```
public class LogDataSimulation {

    SharedPreferences defaultPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MyApplication.getAppContext());

    private static final String TAG = "LogDataSimulation";
    public static boolean simulatedDataEnabled;
    WMManager wmManager = new WMManager();

    public LogDataSimulation() {
        simulatedDataEnabled = defaultPreferences.getBoolean(kSimulationMode, false);
    }

    public synchronized void simulatedUpdate() {
        InputStream logFileStream = null;
        try {
            AssetManager assetManager = MyApplication.getAppContext().getAssets();
            logFileStream = assetManager.open("file.csv");

            InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(logFileStream, Charset.defaultCharset());

            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(streamReader);
            String[] nextLine;

            double headingAccuracy = 0.0;
            double strideAccuracy = 0.0;
            double currentStepLength = 0.0;
            int totalStepCount = 0;
            double cumulativeDistance = 0.0;
            double latitude = 0.0;
            double longitude = 0.0;
            double altitude = 0.0;
            double userHeading = 0.0;
            Location globalLocation = new Location("");
            int floorID = 0;
            double stepBias = 0.0;
            double stepBiasAccuracy = 0.0;
            double orientationBias = 0.0;
            double orientationBiasAccuracy = 0.0;

            TestUpdate update = new TestUpdate();
            boolean header = true;
            while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                if (nextLine[2].equalsIgnoreCase("data")) {
                    //Throw the header.
                    if (header) {
                        header = false;
                        continue;
                    }
                    headingAccuracy = Double.valueOf(nextLine[17]);
                    strideAccuracy = Double.valueOf(nextLine[22]);
                    currentStepLength = Double.valueOf(nextLine[24]);
                    totalStepCount = Integer.valueOf(nextLine[25]);
                    cumulativeDistance = Double.valueOf(nextLine[26]);
                    latitude = Double.valueOf(nextLine[30]);
                    longitude = Double.valueOf(nextLine[31]);
                    altitude = Double.valueOf(nextLine[32]);
                    userHeading = Double.valueOf(nextLine[36]);
                    globalLocation = update.globalParticlesLocation();
                    floorID = 10000;
                    stepBias = Double.valueOf(nextLine[39]);
                    stepBiasAccuracy = Double.valueOf(nextLine[41]);
                    orientationBias = Double.valueOf(nextLine[43]);
                    orientationBiasAccuracy = Double.valueOf(nextLine[46]);
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }

                wmManager.receivedUpdate(longitude, latitude,
                        altitude, totalStepCount, cumulativeDistance, currentStepLength,
                        strideAccuracy, userHeading, headingAccuracy, floorID,
                        globalLocation, stepBias, stepBiasAccuracy, orientationBias,
                        orientationBiasAccuracy);


            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

The Logged Error is:
I get a W/System.err: at com.app.navigationSimulation.LogDataSimulation.simulatedUpdate(LogDataSimulation.java:95) Line 95 is the the call to wmManager.receivedUpdate() and the Exception message: Cannot invoke setValue on a background thread

Comment: I get a W/System.err:     at com.app.navigationSimulation.LogDataSimulation.simulatedUpdate(LogDataSimulation.java:95) Line 95 is the the call to wmManager.receivedUpdate() and the Exception message: Cannot invoke setValue on a background thread

Comment: The details have been added